# ufw delete allow 'Nginx HTTP': Could not delete non-existent rule, but it does exist

Tags: server, firewall, nginx, ufw

I have successfully set up nginx using [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04), but one part has never worked for me, and that bothers me even though it does not seem to cause an problems.

```
root@devtest:/home/dev-admin# ufw app list
Available applications:
  Nginx Full
  Nginx HTTP
  Nginx HTTPS
  OpenSSH
root@devtest:/home/dev-admin# sudo ufw delete allow 'Nginx HTTP'
Could not delete non-existent rule
Could not delete non-existent rule (v6)
root@devtest:/home/dev-admin# ufw app list
Available applications:
  Nginx Full
  Nginx HTTP
  Nginx HTTPS
  OpenSSH
```

What am I missing here?
Is this not the correct syntax to delete the rule?
This is on Ubuntu 20.04, but I get the same result on 18.04.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks, you can put that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man ufw`, the command `ufw app list`

> list[s] the names of application profiles known to ufw

(these are all the profiles stored in the `/etc/ufw/applications.d/` directory). The output does not imply that rules for those profiles have been added to the running firewall - to see that information, use

```
ufw status verbose
```

Comment: And as you can see from your commands, @Stonecraft, you don't have a rule enabling that profile, so.. ;)